# Electron - build an installer for Windows x64 on Mac

Tags: electron, windows-installer, electron-builder, electron-packager

I am new to electron and trying to build a windows installer for the electron app using my mac. I am using electron-packager to package the app and then electron-wix-msi to build the installer. When the build installer steps are executed, the error `Unable to read file info from exe. Falling back to packaging description. Error: spawn Unknown system error -86` is thrown. please see the full error message in the attached screenshot.

I would like to highlight that when I build an installer for macOS, it works. Should I understand that I can not build a windows installer using mac?

[image]

build_installer64.ts file:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that, you have to do this on the Windows platform.
I use GitHub Actions to build my app for each platform, code for Windows:
https://sudovanilla.com/code/Korbs/electron-builder-sample/src/branch/main/.github/workflows/build.yml#L52-L71

Optionally, you can also use a Windows virtual machine and repeat the same process in there.

---

Update, for those interested in doing this on Linux, building a EXE setup file seems to be possible. You'll need to have `wine` installed and use:

```bash
npx electron-builder build --win
```

Comment: Thank you @korbs for sharing this information.

Comment: That link seems to be dead @Korbs, would it be possible to re-upload, I need something similar, thanks!